# CSS not showing in mozilla chrome

Tags: css, firefox, webkit

I am working on one website and came across css issue. Mozilla and Chrome not taking css.
Please help me out from this. I have checked the url on w3.validator site it showing me OK.

Here is website link: http://adtrack.seoperspective.com

Thanks,
Praful

Comment: [It looks fine to me](http://i.imgur.com/qMgvm.png). Make sure to clear your browser cache and then try to reload the page.

Comment: @Blender I get a different output. I'm missing the input shadows and the gradient. Chrome 22

Comment: @JanDvorak: I'm running Chrome 22 as well.

Comment: Please clear browser cache ..

Comment: I'm getting a failed GET request to http://adtrack.seoperspective.com/style/style.css (no response) but accessing through opening in a separate window works.

Comment: i am using mozilla 16 and chrome 22 if you have firebug on mozilla you can't see style.css but after doing view source it shows style.css and clicking on it loads css file

Comment: @JanDvorak its must have black background which is coded in css style.css

Comment: the inline style works fine but there is problem with css file i guess

Comment: Perhaps they are choking on `@charset "utf-8";`. This seems nonstandard to me.

Comment: @JanDvorak does file permissions affects it, I have set 0777 to folder style and style.css

Comment: @praful server shouldn't be aware/concerned if it's being accessed directly or as a part of a document. File permissions issue would result in a 403 on direct access

Comment: i just remove @charset "utf-8"; but still the problem is there what should i do please suggest

Comment: I'll try to intercept the communication in Fiddler

Comment: Hmm... I can't even see the CSS request in fiddler.

Comment: Chrome shows the `link` outside `head` but it's inside in the source code.

Comment: Got it! It works in a private window.

Comment: @JanDvorak thanks for your time man but i guess adblock was doing trick disabling adblock add-on on mozilla worked for me , sorry for all trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the style isn't loaded because your domain gets filtered by AdBlock.

Namely, it trips the following rule in the EasyList: `/adtrack.`

If I disable AdBlock and reload, the CSS file gets loaded and applied, complete with shadows and a black background.

There is no easy solution but changing your third-level domain to something that isn't offensive to AdBlock.

Answer (score 0):

your CSS is protected by login.php:6.

Edit: or it's because of of the adtrack URL. But in any case, when I try to open the styles.css in a new window, I get rerouted to the login page.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, never know adblock was blocking this !

Comment: When I try to open the styles.css in a new window, I _don't_ get any redirect.

Comment: you are right, not sure how that happened. Can't reproduce it either... sry. I may have just clicked on the login URL by mistake... *gets more coffee now*